# Invalid Pointer Error when using free()

Tags: python, c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a Python Extension in C (on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)) and ran into an issue with dynamic memory allocation. I searched through SO and found several posts on free() calls causing similar errors because free() tries to free memory that is not dynamically allocated. But I don't know if/how that is a problem in the code below:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static PyObject* tirepy_process_data(PyObject* self, PyObject *args)
{
    FILE* rawfile = NULL;
    char* rawfilename = (char *) malloc(128*sizeof(char));
    if(rawfilename == NULL)
         printf("malloc() failed.\n");
    memset(rawfilename, 0, 128);
    const int num_datapts = 0; /* Just  Some interger variable*/

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "si", &rawfilename, &num_datapts)) {
          return NULL;
    }

    /* Here I am going top open the file, read the contents and close it again */

    printf("Raw file name is: %s \n", rawfilename);
    free(rawfilename);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", num_profiles);
}
```

The output is:

```
Raw file name is: \home\location_to_file\
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb7514244 ***
```

Comment: It would be interesting to see what `PyArg_ParseTuple` does and what it expects as arguments. Also note that you can get rid of the malloc [cast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3194340)

Comment: I'd also suggest using `calloc()`. Also, the size of a char is by definition 1, as all sizes are measured in multiples of a char. Oh, and please don't `printf()` errors but signal them to the caller!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html):

> These formats allow to access an object as a contiguous chunk of memory. **You don’t have to provide raw storage for the returned unicode or bytes area**. Also, you won’t have to release any memory yourself, except with the es, es#, et and et# formats.

<sup>(Emphasis is added by me)</sup>

So you do not need to first allocate memory with `malloc()`. You also do not need to `free()` the memory afterwards.

Your error occurs because you are trying to free memory that was provided/allocated by Python. So C (malloc/free) is unable to free it, as it is unknown to the C runtime.

Comment: It may even been allocated from a custom memory pool.

Comment: @Kamajii Indeed, the base line is that `free()` fails, because the memory was not obtained by `malloc()`.

Comment: Can maybe you explain for dummies what you mean? You are saying what not to do, but not what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the API docs for `PyArg_ParseTuple': https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html

You shall NOT pass a pointer to allocated memory, nor shall you free it afterwards.

Comment: Alternatively, use some of the `es` format specifiers.